# Can't make null value for DateTimeProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jinja2

I am using a DateTimeProperty on GAE Datastore.

```
date_posted = db.DateTimeProperty()
```

I then need to make a comparison with jinja2.

```
{% if i.date_posted is defined %}
  {{ i.date_posted.strftime('%d %b %Y') }}
{% else %}
  No
{% endif %}
```

On GAE SDK Console, my entry says:

> date_posted (None)

But my comparison doesn't pick it up as null.

Comment: I don't know Jinja2 that well: is there a difference between being defined and being None? ie could it be defined as None?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
{{ i.date_posted.strftime('%d %b %Y')  if i.date_posted != None  }}
```

Comment: Perfect! I just had to add a "else 'No'" and it was sorted.  Thank you.